# Proof of homomorphism theorem in S. Langs Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, solution-verification

I'm having difficulties understanding the proof of Theorem XI.3.1 in S. Lang's *Algebra*.

There is one argument the reader has to fill in himself and I am not sure if I did it correctly:

> Suppose $k[a_1, \ldots, a_n]$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra without zero-divisors ($k$ a perfect field).
> Suppose also that $K = k(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ has transcendence degree 1 over $k$.
> Then $K = k(u)[v]$ and there is an irreducible polynomial $f \in k[X,Y]$ such that $f(u,v) = 0$

If $f$ has infinitely many zeros in $k$ then I can find one zero $(a,b) \in k^2$
such that none of the denominators of the $a_i$ vanish on $(a,b)$.
Then I can extend the homomorphism $k[u,v] \to k$ given by $(u,v) \to (a,b)$
to $k[a_1, \ldots, a_n] \to k$. Is this argument correct?
In the proof he seems to emphasize that $\partial_Y f(a,b) \ne 0$ but it seems to me, that he does not need it?

Comment: Please make this question self-contained by including *all* the relevant portions of this proof. Without this information you are less likely to get answers: any potential respondent has to go dig up their copy of the book (if they even have it), find the proof, dig through it on their own just to know what you're asking about, and then they can start thinking about how to answer your question. This creates unnecessary obstacles to you getting an answer. For instance, what is $K$? You do not define this.

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten to define $K$, which is just the quotient field of $R[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$. I tried to make my question more clear. It is a bit difficult because the proof is quite long.

Comment: I did another edit. Now it is more clear, I think.